# how can I get 50 (something) if you won't let me write one because I have not 50 'credits' I think?

Tags: discussion

I heard a joke in "the vicar of Dibley" (most episodes do end up with one told by Dawn French, the vicar, to her not so bright friend...) And I could not understand it. I kind of found the answer here. But did not agree with some of the statements about the explanation. When I clicked on "Comment" I was told I did not have enough "Credits" may be! My question is how will I get these credits if I'm not allowed to write comments?

Comment: Please link the question you are referring to. If the question is open and not "protected" you can post an answer instead if a comment. Answers that ate upvoted give their authors "rep" (credit/ reputation points)

Comment: Stupid auto correct or fat finfers take your pick...

Comment: Stack Exchange is **not** a discussion forum, so discussing answers is not welcome. Note that if you disagree with an answer, you can write your own (and you might get reputation awarded for it). The duplicate question covers the generalities. However, it appears in your case you should ask a new question, referencing the one you found and explaining why the answers don't help.

Comment: You get credits by asking and answering questions. Comments will not earn you any credits, even if they are up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

[Reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) points are earned by asking or answering questions. When you do that, those posts can be voted upon by other users. When somebody votes for your answers or awards you a bountty, you gain some, and when somebody votes against them you or you vote against an answer (but not a question) you lose some. A vote for a question gets you five; a vote for an answer gets you ten; a vote against one of your posts loses you two and a voting against an answer costs 1. Less often you might get your answer accepted  by the questioner which gives you 15, or win a bounty from another user, at their cost, which can be awarded in increments of 50 up to a limit of 500.

Commenting is a [privilege](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that you have to earn because we are focused on questions and answers, so we do not just want people commenting willy nilly. We want people to have some familiarity with the website so they know how to comment. You can read the full commentary guidelines [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). The major ones are no answering in the comments (which is important, but often ignored), and to focus your comments primarily towards leaving constructive criticism, or leaving behind transient information which may be deleted later like relevant links to related resources.

Also you might do well to read as much of [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) as you can prior to contributing because we have many similar expectations which can catch users off-guard.